# How to prevent Gnome and XFCE desktops from overlapping

Tags: gnome, xfce, desktop

I noticed a weird behaviour in my XFCE sessions. The DE starts fine and at a certain point, I still don't know what causes this, the XFCE desktop is transparently overlapped by the Gnome one.

All my icons are duplicated, and the XFCE ones are unclickable. When I left click on the background, I get Gnome options and the Gnome desktop managing utility. Curiously changing the wallpaper in that utility has no effect on the XFCE session.

[image: XFCE Issue Image]

While this is clearly a bug, is it a known one? Where should I check to see what's happening? Who should I report it to, if need be?

Answer (score -2):

I faced this issue with XFCE 4.12 in Centos 7.

I tried to remove/hide the GNOME desktop icons using the suggestions from here https://askubuntu.com/a/10896157 Unfortunately none of them worked.

So I removed/hid the desktop icons of XFCE instead, using the following

`Applications --> Settings --> Desktop --> Icons --> Appearance --> Icon type: --> None`

[image]

At least, now I have a workable desktop.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm afraid this answer doesn't address the question, because the core problem is why a second desktop environment emerges in the first place. Also, the answer on AskUbuntu you linked to doesn't exist anymore.